# different DB type boolean in production and development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I have a migration including the following type:

```
create_table :products do |t|
    t.boolean :overdue
end
```

in my development setup though (Postgresql 9.1, rails 3.2.11) I have to test

```
p.overdue == "t" # or
p.overdue == "f"
```

p.overdue? or p.overdue == true or p.overdue == false doesn't work.

On heroku (I resently created the test app, so I guess ts cedar, PG 9.1 as well) I can test p.overdue? or p.overdue == true, while  the test on the string "t" or "f" doesn't work.

Am I missing some configuration option in my development setup?

Comment: what does the schema.rb in your app say?

Comment: schema.rb had t.binary, while the migration said t.boolean. This was an error I corrected, but I had only done rake db:reset, which only reloads teh schema, but doesn't first run the migrations. That was it. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schema.rb had t.binary, while the migration said t.boolean. This was an error I had corrected, but I had only run

```
rake db:reset
```

which only reloads the schema, but does not run the migrations. Either correct the schema and run db:reset again, or better yet run:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```